# LRU algorithm to determine which block to be replaced

Tags: algorithm

> For its on-chip cache, the 80486 uses a replacement algorithm called pseudo least recently used.  Associated with each of the 128 sets of four lines (labeled L0, L1, L2, and L3) are three bits B0, B1, and B2.  The replacement algorithm works as follows:  When a line must be replaced, the cache will first determine whether the most recent use was from the pair L0/L1 or the pair L2/L3. Then the cache will determine which of the pair of blocks was least recently used and mark it for replacement. Specify how the bits B0, B1, and B2 are used in this replacement algorithm and demonstrate that this only approximates a true LRU algorithm through an example of a line useage order where this algorithm will differ from the LRU algorithm.

I am confused on how to go about answering this question. We didn't hardly talk about LRU at all let alone algorithms to implement it. Could it run like this: if B0 is 0, then L0/L1 are used. If B0 is 1, then L2/ L3 are used. From there though I don't know what to do with B1 and B2. Can anyone help explain this to me?

Comment: It's customary in an LRU cache to preserve the order of data based on *when* an item is accessed. When an item is accessed, it becomes the most recently accessed item, and when the cache becomes full, the *least* recently accessed item is purged. So make sure that you have some way of keeping track of the most recently accessed and least recently accessed items (think of a doubly linked list). [Here is a good example of a high level implementation of an LRU cache](https://github.com/rsms/js-lru) and its design is also explained briefly.

Comment: It looks like B0 addresses the two line pairs L0/L1 or L2/L3, B2 addresses the line within each pair, and B3 is the mark-for-replacement flag.